# Extract view fields with token replaced

Tags: 7, views, tokens

I have a "view" that return me the JSON fields version (views_datasource is the module I use). One of this fields is a field of type "Long text" where is present 1 token [mytoken] that in the normal node view (node/123) display some images.

In the JSON output of this field I don't want to see the string "[mytoken]" but images. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you getting the view?

Comment: For view output I use view datasource so I can send the result in JSON format, but I think that i have not understand what do you ask me.  If necessary, I can use a PHP view custom field that permit to use token_replace, but how ?

Comment: ? So you have a view that is displayed the node page and it displays correctly? But does not display correctly in the JSON view? Please explain your situation a bit better in the original post. Now, it is a little hard to understand how you are displaying your views.